# Can't generic list in another class type in a class

Tags: c#, list, console-application

The class for which I want to create a generic list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace GameDemoProject
{
    class HomePage
    {
        List<Game> games = new List<Game>();
        //I can't produce list items like games.Add(1,"Call Of Duty",300); 
    }   
}
```

Here is the type of class I want to make the list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace GameDemoProject
{
    class Game
    {
        public int GameID { get; set; }
        public string GameName { get; set; }
        public int GamePrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you need to use `games.Add(new Game(...));` I'd suggest writing a constructor in your `Game` class - and also removing the `Game` prefix from all those properties.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your suggestions. I can't write "games.Add" because when I trying to write it underlines the text in red.

Comment: Create constructor inside game class !

Comment: @MehmetAzizAlgüllü: Well what error message does it give when you try to build it? The compiler error messages are there to give information - please share that information with us. Once you've got a suitable Game constructor, it should be fine.

Comment: @MehmetAzizAlgüllü i guess main method is required you have to create main method inside HomePage

Comment: Bhavya is right; the elements allowed on the top level inside a class are members (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members). You can not just write `games.Add(...)` at that level. You should either do that in a constructor (or some method) or use an appropriate initializer for the games list; `List<Games> games = new List<Games> { new Game(...), new Game(...) };`

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for not sharing bug notes, I'm new to the community yet. Here are the mistakes I get: IDE1007: The name 'games.Add' does not exist in the current context. IDE1007: The name 'games' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @BhavyaParikh I guess you're right because the code was running in the main method. So what is the reason for this?

Comment: @MehmetAzizAlgüllü: It doesn't have to be a Main method, but you need *some* method to run the code in. Currently your HomePage class just has a field - that's all. You'll need to put the code in a method or a constructor. At the moment this question is too broad really - it's not actually about lists at this point.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. I found a solution like this. I added the main method inside the HomePage class. I can write "games.Add" this way. Do you think this is the right solution? Can there be more than one main function in a project as "static void Main (string [] args)"?

Comment: @MehmetAzizAlgüllü: Stack Overflow is not designed for comment threads to be used for follow-up questions. Do research first, and then ask a new question if you have to. (But ask yourself *why* you'd want more than one Main method.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot. I will read your book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

The list stores games so `Add` accepts a game object. `Add` does not accpet game's properties.

### Options

Here's my favourite option.

```
class Game
{
    public Game(int id, string name, decimal price)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; }
}
```

Then:

```
List<Game> games = new List<Game>();

var game1 = new Game(1,"Call Of Duty",300); // I'd even use named parameters
games.Add(game1);

// or

games.Add(new Game(2,"Tetris",1));
```

Here's 2nd best:

```
class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
games.Add( new Game{ Id = 1, Name = "Call Of Duty", Price = 300});
```

Answer (score 1):

`games` is the `List` of `Game`, so you can only add `Game` object to this list. so you can do like this `games.Add(new Game(1,"Call Of Duty",300));`. you need to the respective constructor also to the `Game` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't write "games.Add" because when I trying to write it underlines the text in red.

Comment: IDE1007: The name 'games.Add' does not exist in the current context.
IDE1007: The name 'games' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: can you please clean the solution and build again, it might be showing you the cached error? or try reopening the visual studio if clean does not work..and make sure you are using the `games` in the correct scopt